# Different collation behaviour between ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 for Thai

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, locale

There are two virtualbox machines on vagrant boxes ubuntu/bionic64 and bento/ubuntu-20.04 (first one is ubuntu 18.04 and the later is ubuntu 20.04). Once booted, we define locale en_US.UTF-8 with `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. Now the locale settings should be identical in both:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Now we can try to sort two specific thai strings:

```
vagrant@bionic:~$ sort << eof
> ธรรมสถาน
> ศาลเจ้า
> eof
```

The above returns different results for the two LTSs.
For ubuntu 20.04:

```
ธรรมสถาน
ศาลเจ้า
```

For ubuntu 18.04:

```
ศาลเจ้า
ธรรมสถาน
```

I have been banging my head to grasp what's wrong but to no avail. The only potentially relevant source that I've found so far is the [ICU reference section](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/collation/concepts.html#thailao-reordering) about special handling of Thai/Lao characters, but I would not expect this to cause such an inconsistency. I also don't speak any Thai so I have no idea about lexicographic ordering rules of the Thai alphabet, to judge what seems to be correct and not.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue? Is it possible to preserve the sort order between the two releases somehow?

Comment: A link called "this" does not meet accessibility rules. Please edit to give a decent name.

Comment: Updated, thanks!